# Failed to install HelloWorld.apk on device

Tags: android

> [2015-04-27 22:12:51 - HelloWorld] ------------------------------
>   [2015-04-27 22:12:51 - HelloWorld] Android Launch!
>   [2015-04-27 22:12:51 - HelloWorld] adb is running normally.
>   [2015-04-27 22:12:51 - HelloWorld] Performing com.example.helloworld.MainActivity activity launch
>   [2015-04-27 22:12:51 - HelloWorld] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'Android1'
>   [2015-04-27 22:12:51 - HelloWorld] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Android1'
>   [2015-04-27 22:14:14 - HelloWorld] New emulator found: emulator-5554
>   [2015-04-27 22:14:14 - HelloWorld] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
>   [2015-04-27 22:17:28 - HelloWorld] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
>   [2015-04-27 22:17:28 - HelloWorld] Uploading HelloWorld.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
>   [2015-04-27 22:17:35 - HelloWorld] Installing HelloWorld.apk...
>   [2015-04-27 22:20:05 - HelloWorld] Failed to install HelloWorld.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
>   [2015-04-27 22:20:05 - HelloWorld] (null)
>   [2015-04-27 22:20:06 - HelloWorld] Launch canceled!

I am getting this error message. Changed DDMS time, checked manifest file for target SDK version, uninstalled and installed ADT plugin, deleted and created AVD, but I did not disable USB debugging. How to do that? Also any other thing I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

USB debugging can be turned off and on in the Developer Settings on your device. You must have developer options turned on to use this. In case you don't, go into About Phone and tap on the Kernel Version 6 times (or until it says you are now a developer).

Comment: The log posted indicates that ADB (what that setting controls) is at least partially operational.

Comment: Will you please elaborate further? I am using AVD. So where is About phone, developer settings etc.?

Comment: In your question, you had asked how to disable USB Debugging. This is something that can be done on a physical Android device...not something you would do on an emulator. Are you trying now to use a physical device? All of those options (About Phone, Developer Settings etc) are found in your Settings.